# Arduino Uno Translate FFT Audio into LEDs and Vibration Motor issue

Tags: audio, arduino, fft, vibration

for a uni project I'm trying to translate frequencies into 4 different vibration motors
I ordered a MSGEQ7 but they are very hard to come by and the order process is taking very long, hence i went the FFT route instead, for the time being.

I first tried the FFT translation with LEDs as outputs for different frequency ranges, as it should be simpler and give a visual feedback.
I asked a friend for help and he coded something that works. However it does not output to the LEDs in question, but according to the monitor it picks up frequencies correctly. Does anyone know what is wrong with the code?
And how could I use this FFT reading to trigger vibration motors as opposed to LED pins on the board?

I'm confused if this even could work with an Arduino Uno since I read it's not possible for a Uno to translate FFTs in real time. That's why the sample size is very small, I think. Would I constantly need to reboot the Board?

Thanks a ton!

````
#define SAMPLES 128 //define according to your need
#define AUDIO A0
#define ledLowsGreen A1
#define ledLowMidsYellow A2
#define ledMidsBlue A3
#define ledHighMidsWhite A4
#define ledHighsRed A5

// array of leds to switch the values
int ledarray[5] = { A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 };
// value to compile the data into 128 / dividor
int dividor = 21;
char im[SAMPLES];
char data[SAMPLES];
int barht[SAMPLES];

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledLowsGreen, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledLowMidsYellow, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledMidsBlue, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledHighMidsWhite, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledHighsRed , OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  static int i, j;
  int val;
  // get audio data
  for (i = 0; i < SAMPLES; i++)
  {
    val = analogRead(AUDIO); // 0-1023
    data[i] = (char)(val / 4 - SAMPLES); // store as char
    im[i] = 0; // init all as 0
  }
  // run FFT
  fix_fft(data, im, 7, 0);
  // extract absolute value of data only, for 32 results
  for (i = 0; i < SAMPLES; i++)
  {
    barht[i] = (int)sqrt(data[i] * data[i] + im[i] * im[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0, j = 0; i < SAMPLES / dividor; i++, j += dividor)
  {
    for (int x = 0 ; x < dividor; x++)
    {
      barht[i] = barht[i] + (barht[j + x]);
    }
  }

// display 5 leds
for (int k = 1; k < SAMPLES / dividor; k++) {
      analogWrite(ledarray[5],barht[k]);
     }


  // display Serial plotter
  for (int k = 1; k < SAMPLES / dividor; k++) {
    Serial.print("Band_");
    Serial.print(k);
    Serial.print(":");
    if ( k + 1 == (SAMPLES / dividor))
    {
      Serial.println();
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.print(", ");
    }
  }

  for (int k = 1; k < SAMPLES / dividor; k++) {
    Serial.print(barht[k]);
    //analogWrite(ledarray[5],barht[k])
    if ( k + 1 == (SAMPLES / dividor))
    {
      Serial.println();
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.print(", ");
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This looks to be a few problems all wrapped up in one. One thing to make sure of is, can you get your components to behave, in isolation with known values and an expected result. E.g if you analogWrite the value 5 to your ledArray, what should happen? The same is true of the vibration motor. Once you have that, then you can start feeding it the absolute values of the FFT bins. You may also want to spread out the sections of loop into separate functions

Comment: a) "Constantly reboot the board" is definitely nothing helpful. b)  Not sure if the compiler can see that `SAMPLES/dividor` is a constant c) LEDs are faster than  vibration motors, and can be controlled directly. For motors, I guess you need extra electronics.